# PostgreSql join with 1 row of records

Tags: postgresql

Any ideas how to join with only 1 row of data?
i have 3 tables,three of them have millions of data.

[image: My tables]

```
select A.service_id,case when C.parameter is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as status from service_option A
inner join treng.transaction_job B
on B.service_option_id=A.id
and A.service_id in (1,4)
LEFT join transaction_params C
on B.id=C.transaction_params
and parameter like '%na%'
```

and below is my expected result.

[image: Expected result]

As we can see the 2nd table i have 2 rows of data but i want to join 1 row of data only,same case to table no.3

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: The column names in the query don't match those in the tables.